# A.T. = Appalachian Trail in sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've found this sentence in Google Books:

> Somewhat more permanent are small anodized metal “**A.T.**” diamonds that
>   the original trailblazers nailed along the path in the 1930s and
>   1940s.

[Context here](https://books.google.de/books?id=0Fj6BJV8hg4C&pg=PA106&dq=%22trailblazers%20nailed%20along%20the%20path%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1wZ2knfXUAhWIZlAKHTNBAiMQ6AEIFjAA#v=onepage&q=%22trailblazers%20nailed%20along%20the%20path%22&f=false).

Am I right that "A.T." means "Appalachian Trail" here? The following sentence in Wikipedia made me think so:

> The Appalachian National Scenic Trail, generally known as the
>   Appalachian Trail or simply the **A.T.**, is a marked hiking trail in the
>   Eastern United States extending between Springer Mountain in Georgia
>   and Mount Katahdin in Maine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The referenced book's context is specifically along the Appalachian Trail, or 'A.T.'. As well, 'A.T.' is common nomenclature for those familiar with the trail.